# ListViewItem content not filling width

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, styles, width

Here is some XAML code I'm using to bind a list of items which contain an image of an architecture. My images appear correctly, but does not fill the width of the ListViewItem, though the height is filled properly. My images are also square, so I know that this is not happening since there is no evident distortion of the image.

Additionally, I notice that the ListViewItem has a light grey background color where it should be transparent, or null/none.

Anybody has any idea how to get the binding right?

```
                <ListView x:Name="listView_Architecture" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="listView_Architecture_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Style>
                            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding SetupImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you paste the snapshot here that what's it like showing up on UI?

Comment: Have you tried setting the ListViewItem style's HorizontalAlignment also to "Stretch"?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite hard to understand what you are actually asking there.

You first mention the image is not fitting the complete size then you jump over to grey background thingy and then you end up talking about Bindings. What exactly is the question?

I will answer you the first one. Those others are easy and I guess you will find those answers by yourself. Binding aint that hard to understand and Input Window in Visual Studio will give you all kind of information about what you did wrong in your Bindings

The reason why the Image is not taking all the available space is because the Image doesnt know how much space is free there.

When ListView is being measured and its children are being arranged it will calculate and set the height value to its children so the children know about the height but width will not be set on each child. Therefore your Image cannot find an ancestor to receive available Width from and so it doesnt know what width value to take for stretching and so futhermore it will be displayed at its normal size since that is the default value when no other found.

If you wish to test this behavior just set a fix width value in style of ListViewItem. If you set the value to 200 pixels the Image will be stretched to the width of 200. Though when you not set any width there will be no value found for Image to know how to stretch itself.

That easy. :)